# how do i solve the application error on heroku flask app?

Tags: python, flask, heroku

bonjour everyone.

i've an "application error" on heroku flask app

i don't even know what i'm supposed to show so i' mjust gonna show this :

```
2020-12-12T16:34:38.202986+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T16:34:38.202986+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T16:34:38.324998+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T16:34:38.324998+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T16:34:52.671625+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=3dc38ea0-3274-482b-ab25-54810e644c66 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T16:34:54.553310+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code=H81 desc="Blank app" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=702f1c13-272d-477c-9a1e-3e608f91bbce fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=502 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:24:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T17:25:09.806664+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T17:25:09.806664+00:00 app[api]: Deploy fdbeb30b by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T17:25:09.824291+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T17:25:12.858841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn app:tuto`
2020-12-12T17:25:14.431343+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-12T17:25:14.462293+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-12T17:25:14.466111+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-12T17:25:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-12-12T17:25:17.698991+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn app:tuto`
2020-12-12T17:25:20.343513+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-12T17:25:20.378595+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-12T17:26:32.998759+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=d2ae02c5-e68e-48dc-aa2b-a15bec775253 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:26:34.694736+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=2386321c-000a-426d-a7dc-15a463db822f fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:27:56.030578+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=52f251df-6be0-4a17-99e9-64d4fc03b07c fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:27:56.967195+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=95c61b41-e203-4bdf-801e-47fa99d12c90 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:38:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T17:38:46.996007+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T17:38:46.996007+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0bb4e9a7 by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T17:38:48.418866+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-12T17:38:51.556021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn app:tuto`
2020-12-12T17:38:53.798514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-12T17:38:53.849825+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-12T17:38:53.853438+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-12T17:38:54.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-12-12T17:38:58.631983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn app:tuto`
2020-12-12T17:39:02.685672+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-12T17:39:02.728577+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-12T17:40:23.683784+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=f863ea53-d07f-45d0-a52f-d5a240ae8375 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:40:25.405822+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=9b859b32-8798-4ffe-bf17-9c5e2cb1081c fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:43:26.685628+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=1f046546-456a-4aa3-99f6-08540b1b4f2a fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:43:29.482685+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=2bbbe644-69f9-4b1e-99b5-a958f93d2cff fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:52:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T17:53:23.443186+00:00 app[api]: Deploy e0ced2ae by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T17:53:23.443186+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T17:53:24.737970+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-12T17:53:27.791777+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn app:tuto`
2020-12-12T17:53:29.695868+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-12T17:53:29.731259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-12T17:53:29.734243+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-12T17:53:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-12-12T17:53:32.484091+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn app:tuto`
2020-12-12T17:53:33.913367+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-12T17:53:33.947223+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-12T17:53:53.313902+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=8bd3736f-b293-4f8d-ad8f-9b4c245effc0 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:53:55.920783+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=48002cd3-fbe9-4353-8a6e-ce5260962392 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:54:04.443857+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/index" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=e6c56ece-baad-4d37-a468-7709fcc2dfc5 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:54:06.268870+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=aa3cd9bc-90bc-44c5-9bae-8b77c5e940a6 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:54:11.361192+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=3d98f3ce-c996-48e6-87a8-e25f7735d02f fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T17:54:12.739761+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=9a115339-67ce-4449-9d48-ae3fac0ae165 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T18:09:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T18:09:57.634847+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 2b6ce08f by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T18:09:57.634847+00:00 app[api]: Release v6 created by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T18:09:58.749906+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-12T18:10:03.285472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn app:tuto`
2020-12-12T18:10:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-12-12T18:10:06.060271+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-12T18:10:06.116409+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-12T18:10:06.120611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-12T18:10:09.832708+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn app:tuto`
2020-12-12T18:10:12.348256+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-12T18:10:12.397746+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-12T18:14:58.113716+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=733c54ab-5cdb-4109-81df-129d31a34e26 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T18:15:00.078873+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=0c61b666-430c-4361-928e-6e0b1a2d9382 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T18:23:17.255686+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=31c1b954-df99-4181-8881-5296db924a82 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T18:23:19.030246+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=cec8bf1f-5254-4589-b99d-f8f6857d52f6 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T18:29:54.968505+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=f51ae23a-b5af-4c8b-96e6-c5ad1a6eac18 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T18:29:56.845057+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=bdd145cb-211e-450b-99df-4a51241016ce fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T18:32:23.154430+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-12T18:32:26.002504+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn app:tuto`
2020-12-12T18:32:27.890403+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-12T18:32:27.925750+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-12T18:32:27.929229+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-12T18:32:30.890019+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn app:tuto`
2020-12-12T18:32:32.713562+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-12T18:32:32.747388+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-12T18:37:16.718521+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=27a2efc0-9062-4d53-9c6c-cb370d343112 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-12-12T18:37:18.878133+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=a3d3bb9e-cba7-4525-8372-96e85b41e746 fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2020-12-12T18:37:39.866820+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=3423baa5-5884-4354-b3d2-57eff39dd9be fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T18:37:41.220783+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=c8c30f5f-4aa5-4052-a318-237a4eda092a fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T19:02:00.314095+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-12T19:02:03.327441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn app:tuto`
2020-12-12T19:02:05.068649+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-12T19:02:05.111975+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-12T19:03:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T19:04:13.564584+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 076a103f by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T19:04:13.564584+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user alainelomapro@gmail.com
2020-12-12T19:04:14.901646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-12T19:04:19.851140+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: gunicorn -b :26494 app:tuto`
2020-12-12T19:04:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-12-12T19:04:22.295995+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-12-12T19:04:22.333013+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-12T19:04:33.076019+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=82238418-b900-433a-9aed-44f472a97cdc fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-12-12T19:04:37.476471+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intothedetails.herokuapp.com request_id=51d7b972-f737-4098-b292-210ebd1311cf fwd="105.178.116.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

it appaers after i typed on "heroku logs --tail"

i've seen somewhere i should edit the procfile with : -b :$PORT

```
web : gunicorn -b :$PORT app:tuto
```

but then i don't even know how far i need to go back for it to be in my file. should i "git init" again ?
i'm lost, tired and more and more annoyed lol

my python code :

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import re
from collections import *

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def getvalue():
    letexte = request.form['letexte']
    user_input = request.form['user_input']
    user_title = request.form['user_title']
    input_two = request.form['input_two']
    
    lowercase_words = letexte.lower()
    
    tokenized = word_tokenize(lowercase_words)
    words = len(lowercase_words.split(' '))
    sentences = sent_tokenize(letexte)
    no_sent = len(sentences)
    
    def count_unique_words(text_string):
        word_list = re.split('; |, |\*|\n |\s', text_string)
        return list(dict.fromkeys(word_list))
    uniq_words = len(count_unique_words(letexte))
    
    nouns = []
    list_most_occur = []
    for w in tokenized:
        if len(w) > 2 and w[0]:
            nouns.append(w)
    
    counter_variables = Counter(nouns)
    most_occur = counter_variables.most_common(10)
    
    for mo in most_occur:
        list_most_occur.append(mo)
        
    input_count = tokenized.count(user_input)
    
    lesphrases = [ t for t in letexte.split('. ') or letexte.split('? ') or letexte.split('! ') if input_two in t]
    
    return render_template('return.html',ut=user_title, ltxt=letexte, w=words, uw=uniq_words, s=no_sent, lmo=list_most_occur,ui=user_input, ic=input_count, it=input_two, lp=lesphrases)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

my html form

```html
<form name="passdata" action="." method="POST" target="_blank">
                    <label for="subject">Subject Text</label>
                    <textarea id="subject" name="letexte" placeholder="" style="height:160px"></textarea>

                    <label for="fname">word 1</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="user_input" placeholder="how many times it appeard?">

                    <label for="fname">word 2</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" name="input_two" placeholder="sentences with the word">
                
                    <label for="lname">title</label>
                    <input type="text" id="lname" name="user_title" placeholder="">
                    </select>
                
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the app is building to the container without issue but is crashing when it starts up.  I'm not exactly sure why it is crashing when trying to get your home url '/'.

Regarding the favicon issue the below code helps flask find static assets and may help the app launch.

```
from flask import send_from_directory,


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('test.html')


@app.route('/return', methods=['POST'])
def getvalue():
    letexte = request.form['letexte']
    user_input = request.form['user_input']
    user_title = request.form['user_title']
    input_two = request.form['input_two']
    
    lowercase_words = letexte.lower()
    
    tokenized = word_tokenize(lowercase_words)
    words = len(lowercase_words.split(' '))
    sentences = sent_tokenize(letexte)
    no_sent = len(sentences)
    
    def count_unique_words(text_string):
        word_list = re.split('; |, |\*|\n |\s', text_string)
        return list(dict.fromkeys(word_list))
    uniq_words = len(count_unique_words(letexte))
    
    nouns = []
    list_most_occur = []
    for w in tokenized:
        if len(w) > 2 and w[0]:
            nouns.append(w)
    
    counter_variables = Counter(nouns)
    most_occur = counter_variables.most_common(10)
    
    for mo in most_occur:
        list_most_occur.append(mo)
        
    input_count = tokenized.count(user_input)
    
    lesphrases = [ t for t in letexte.split('. ') or letexte.split('? ') or letexte.split('! ') if input_two in t]
    
    return render_template('return.html',ut=user_title, ltxt=letexte, w=words, uw=uniq_words, s=no_sent, lmo=list_most_occur,ui=user_input, ic=input_count, it=input_two, lp=lesphrases)


@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'), 
        'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')
```

Comment: i added my python code. maybe i'll have a better idea of what's wrong

Comment: It looks like you are assigning two different functions to the same endpoint.  Change the routing of the getvalue() function to something like app.route(‘/return’, methods=[‘POST’]).  On your form update the on submit property to hit your new /return endpoint.   Currently you are telling flask to do two different things when you go to the same homepage.

Comment: app.route('/return', methods=['POST'] is not working. i added my html form, i feel like it comes from there...

Comment: You need to update your form action property from <form name="passdata" action=".".    to <form  name="passdata" action="/return">.  This will send the form data to the "/return" view function for processing.

Comment: Awesome, great to hear!  Please mark the original question solved so that others know you got to a resolution. It’s always satisfying to see an app deployment into the real world!

Comment: i though i solved it but...: https://web.facebook.com/photo?fbid=2074678156007110&set=gm.1054788085035945

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this. To solve it I had to make sure all the packages I needed in the requirements.txt file were successfully installed, especially `dnspython`